# KUKA arm's damping ratio

Tags: kuka

Does anyone know how one can calculate the exact damping of KUKA arm during impedance control mode. According to their manual one can control only the Lehr's ratio. However, I want to know the exact value,say in Ns/m.

Comment: What KUKA robot are you using? And what KRC?

Comment: It is LBR iiwa 7.

Answer (score 1):

If Kuka does not specify the damping ratio, then on remaining option is determining it experimentally.

You can excite the structure (e.g. with an excitation hammer) and measure the vibration response (e.g. using accelerometers). Please note that you might need to measure in different poses to compute damping for different joint and to see sensibility to pose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for a theoretical answer and not a experimental one.